# Runtime error 1004 Microsoft excel cannot paste the data in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have two excel sheets. `xlVlookupSheet` is one sheet name and `xlShtCmdb` is another sheet from where it copying the columns data.

I am getting the following error:-

```
Runtime error 1004 Microsoft excel cannot paste the data-
```

It is coming in the second iteration of the below `for loop`. `addressCols` is an array which contains the column names to be copied.

```
    For index = UBound(addressCols) To 0 Step -1
        xlVlookupSheet.Columns("A:A").Insert xlToLeft
         xlShtCmdb.Columns(addressCols(index) & ":" & addressCols(index)).Copy
        xlVlookupSheet.Activate
        xlVlookupSheet.Select
        xlVlookupSheet.Range("A1").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues  
    Next
```

Comment: With a properly assigned array of column letters in `addressCols` this code runs as intended. You may have made a mistake in the *rank* of the array or need to transpose if reading the array from a worksheet range. I would also suggest that the last 4 lines within the loop be merged into `xlVlookupSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`.

Comment: I replaced the last four lines with above code , but same error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that , from where I was copying that excel sheet contains 33767 styles . it will not copy from source to destination if the styles will be more than 3000. Hence i removed the styles and made the simple normal sheet and it worked.

you can get the number of active workbook styles by below code:-

activeworkbook.styles.count

For more information one can go below link:-

http://www.think-cell.com/en/support/kb/0156.shtml